# leave undefined nunjucks variables unrepalced

Tags: templating, nunjucks

This works just fine:

```
nunjucks.renderString('Hello {{ username }}', { username: 'James' });
```

and gives me `'Hello James'`. If I leave out `username` as shown below:

```
nunjucks.renderString('Hello {{ username }}', { noUsername: 'James' });
```

nunjucks gives me `'Hello '`. The behavior I'm trying to define is a way to allow me to leave undefined variables unreplaced so that

```
nunjucks.renderString('Hello {{ username }}', { noUsername: 'James' });
```

gives me `'Hello {{ username }}'`. Is there a way to accomplish this using a custom filter, macro, template, something smarter?  I'd like to avoid rolling my own syntax (custom escape characters) and keep it more idiomatic if possible.  I used `renderString` for a simple example, but I'm going to want to actually use this for entire templates (via `render`).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `{% raw %}` is [a fantastic tag](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#raw) already built in nunjucks that can be used to handle cases where you know your variable will be undefined in advance.  For example, when used as such:

```
nunjucks.renderString('Hello {{ username }} {% raw %}{{ iDoNotExist }}{% endraw %}',
    { username: 'James' });
```

it gives the the following output:

```
'Hello James {{ iDoNotExist }}'
```